# solaris + eeprom + change parameter value

Tags: solaris

by eeprom command that run on Solaris machine I can see displays or changes the values of parameters  in  the   EEPROM

my question - how to change the parameter scsi-initiator-id to 6 in place of 7 ?

I want to change only from  the OS (Solaris) - is it possible ?

```
/var/tmp]# eeprom


ttya-rts-dtr-off=false
ttya-ignore-cd=true
local-mac-address?=true
fcode-debug?=false
scsi-initiator-id=7
oem-logo: data not available.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that

```
eeprom scsi-initiator-id=6
```

would do what you want. The default is 7 because that's usually the address of the host adaptor. Are you sure you want to do this ?

Comment: Hint: You ***probably don't*** want to do this. :-)

Comment: well done - its work  thx so mutch to you